# Show that the sum is between (1,2)

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, sums-of-squares

> Show that the sum
> $$1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots+ \frac{1}{2022^2}$$ is between $(1,2)$, I mean is bigger than $1$ and less than $2$.

What I tried: honestly I never knew or understood how to do this type of exercise, but I have some ideas:

I thought about a formula: $$1/k^2<1/(k-1)×k$$
I can use this one, but I don't think it could help, because I'm only going to prove something with this, I can't calculate.
Should I use the formulas with the terms of the sum, where I find out how many numbers there are in my sum? Any suggestion will help, thanks!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150043/discussion-on-question-by-usee0927-show-that-the-sum-is-between-1-2); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you have:
$$1<\sum_{k=1}^{2022}\frac{1}{k^2}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} $$
Now note that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{k(k+1)}=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=2$$

Comment: ,cant i write it without sigma (sum of )?

Comment: @Usee0927 yes, but when you have an infinite sum you will have to use dots so it's not a compact notation

Comment: im going to send the solving i tought about more clear

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ao2-uPPU1XzpfRYz3PQAkuQIBAtyk6zO/view?usp=drivesdk_italic_

Answer (score 1):

$$1 < \sum_{n=1}^{2022} \frac{1}{n^2} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}<2 $$